# Java Swing Glue not working between 2 buttons

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I am trying to make my own little game in Java as a personal excercise however I am finding a lot of issues using BoxLayout's in Java Swing.

So I have a basic MVC application and I need two buttons at the top both "New Game" and "Submit" to both be on the same line in the GUI. I have found out that I can use glue to do this however all of the guides I have found on it, do not work. Am I missing something obvious here?

[image]This is my view code (my GUI):

```
package mvc;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.*;

public class View extends JFrame {
    //User input Characters
    private JTextField firstChar = new JTextField(1);
    private JTextField secondChar = new JTextField(1);
    private JTextField thirdChar = new JTextField(1);
    private JTextField fourthChar = new JTextField(1);
    private JTextField fifthChar = new JTextField(1);
    
    //Displays on GUI
    private JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    private JButton newButton = new JButton("New Game");

    View() {
        JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
        gamePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(gamePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(600, 200);
        
        gamePanel.add(submitButton);
        gamePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        gamePanel.add(newButton);
        
        gamePanel.add(firstChar);  
        
        gamePanel.add(secondChar);
        gamePanel.add(thirdChar);
        gamePanel.add(fourthChar);
        gamePanel.add(fifthChar);
        
        this.add(gamePanel);
    }
}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

I have tried using glue and rigid area's to solve this however neither worked. I am expecting both buttons to be on the same line in my GUI

Answer (score 0):

You use Boxlayout, that according to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html
*A layout manager that allows multiple components to be laid out either vertically or horizontally.*

In your case it is vertical, and I never used Glue so I am not even aware whether it can change that behaviour.

But you can for sure put the two buttons in an extra panel and add that to your gamePanel, like so:

```
    JPanel buttonBar = new JPanel();
    buttonBar.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    buttonBar.add(submitButton);
    buttonBar.add(newButton);
    gamePanel.add(buttonBar);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, this is much more how I was hoping it would look. I have done the same for my entry fields! Quick question as well, are you able to reduce the gap in between different panels?

Comment: Yes, you can control the gaps - it is all in the LayoutManagers. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Great thanks very much, what is the correct term for this 'gap'?

Comment: @Luke Read the API for the term the API uses. Sometimes the layout manager will directly allow you to control the spacing so there will be methods to control the space between components.  In the case of BoxLayout there is no method, you need to actually add a visible component between the two components. You can control the size of this invisible component.

Comment: BoxLayout call gaps struts - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html. Other LayoutManagers call it margin or padding or insets - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Answer (score 0):

`BoxLayout` can either lay out the components along the `X_AXIS` or along the `Y_AXIS`. You cannot mix this two layout directions with a single `BoxLayout`.

One way to solve your problem is to wrap both buttons in a `JPanel` and use a `BoxLayout(.., BoxLayout.X_AXIS)` to lay out this button panel.

You would then add the button panel as the first element of the `gamePanel`:

```
package mvc;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.*;

public class View extends JFrame {
    //User input Characters
    private JTextField firstChar = new JTextField(1);
    private JTextField secondChar = new JTextField(1);
    private JTextField thirdChar = new JTextField(1);
    private JTextField fourthChar = new JTextField(1);
    private JTextField fifthChar = new JTextField(1);
    
    //Displays on GUI
    private JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    private JButton newButton = new JButton("New Game");

    View() {
        JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
        gamePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(gamePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(600, 200);
        
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        buttonPanel.add(submitButton);
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        buttonPanel.add(newButton);
        gamePanel.add(buttonPanel);

        gamePanel.add(firstChar);  
        
        gamePanel.add(secondChar);
        gamePanel.add(thirdChar);
        gamePanel.add(fourthChar);
        gamePanel.add(fifthChar);
        
        this.add(gamePanel);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also a working method for my application, thank very much Thomas!